# Linq query from c# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have this piece of code from a C# project:

```
public IQueryable<TSource> SearchFor<TSource>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource, bool>> predicate) where TSource : class {
        var query = (from objects in _dataStore
                    where objects is TSource
                     select objects )
                     .Select(o => (TSource)o).AsQueryable();

        return query.Where(predicate);
}
```

(_dataStore = private readonly List())

For a new customer I need to create the same function, but now in VB.NET. This is what I tried;

1:

```
Public Function SearchFor(Of TSource As Class)(ByVal entity As TSource, predicate As Expression(Of Func(Of TSource, Boolean))) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TSource) 
    Dim a = (From o In mDataContext
            Where o Is entity
            Select o).AsQueryable()

    Dim b = a.Where(predicate) '''<--- Error! Error 3   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' can be called with these arguments:... And a lot of more text  

End Function
```

2:

```
Public Function SearchFor(Of TSource As Class)(predicate As Expression(Of Func(Of TSource, Boolean))) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TSource) 
    Dim a = From o In mDataContext
            Where o Is TSource ''' <--- Error! 'TSource' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.

            Select o

    Return mDataContext.Where(predicate)
End Function
```

(mDataContext = As List(Of Object))

4.
[This link](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/). Gave errors after conversion

I' m out of other options. Maybe some one knows how to fix this?

Comment: Unrelated, but migrating from C# to VB.Net is so sad.

Comment: Totaly unrelated, but I know and I did not came with the idea to use VB.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this
(reference of http://converter.telerik.com/)

```
Public Function SearchFor(Of TSource As Class)(predicate As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of TSource, Boolean))) As IQueryable(Of TSource)
    Dim query = (From objects In _dataStore Where TypeOf objects Is TSourceobjects).[Select](Function(o) DirectCast(o, TSource)).AsQueryable()

    Return query.Where(predicate)
End Function
```

Comment: Works! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function SearchFor(Of TSource As Class)(predicate As Expression(Of Func(Of TSource, Boolean))) As IQueryable(Of TSource)
    Dim query = (From objects In _dataStore _
                 Where TypeOf objects Is TSource).Select(Function(o) DirectCast(o, TSource)).AsQueryable()

    Return query.Where(predicate)
End Function
```

Comment: Same as the one that Amit Tiwari posted, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: All converter similar to work together. but some one is not correct, for example this line is not correct: `Where TypeOf objects Is TSourceobjects` because `TSourceobjects` have been `TSource`